# Convert EF 4 add/attach method to EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

For an application running EF 4, I have this method in a repository base class:

```
protected void Add<T>(T source, MyEntities context, bool isNew, EntityState state) where T : class
{
    if (isNew)
    {
        context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AddObject(source);
    }
    else
    {
        if (state == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Attach(source);

            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(source, EntityState.Modified);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine given the version it runs it, but I'm starting a from-scratch new project that will use EF 6.

How can I update the above function to fit EF 6 and work just the same?

I've changed `CreateObjectSet`to `Set`, but then the `AddObject` isn't known.
Doing that does seem to work for the attach, but I have no idea how to replace the `ObjectStateManager` thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDbSet<T>` contains an `Entry<T>()` method which return a `DbEntityEntry<T>` which have a read/write `State` property.

Your code can be converted to the following :

```
protected void Add<T>(T source, MyEntities context, bool isNew) 
    where T : class
{
    IDbSet<T> set = context.Set<T>();
    if (isNew)
    {
        set.Add(source);
    }
    else
    {
        DbEntityEntry<T> entry = set.Entry(source); 
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            set.Attach(source);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! A bonus question if I may, the EF entities themselves no longer seem to have .EntityState, so I can't pass that last parameter. Is there another way to do this?